# Android Studio local.properties

Tags: android

How I can create a `local.properties` that has the following format:

```
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\%username%\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk
```

So that gradle builds can work with any computer that has the sdk in the default location without a need to add the sdk location name manually?

The above example doesn't work...

```
The SDK directory 'C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk' does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `%username%` with the actual username for it to work

i.e. 
`sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\SomeOne\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk`

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually know this to be true, but I would assume that the local.settings file is written in groovy, just like most other settings. In that case, the syntax would be more like:

sdk.dir="C:\Users\$userName\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk"

But even then, I would expect that $userName is not the correct groovy expression for the environment variable that you want to reference. You would have to learn some groovy (as do I!) in order to sort that out.